# Why won't my hard drive work properly on my laptop, but work fine on my desktop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I've been having this issue for the last couple of weeks and I ran out of ideas.

2-3 weeks after adding an SSD to my laptop (alongside a HDD) my hard disk is constantly showing errors and getting removed by Intel RST. So far I tried these in order to find the problem:

-uninstalling Intel RST, which made little to no difference

-booting from a live Ubuntu USB drive, which made no difference

-connected my HDD to my old computer and somehow it worked perfectly (!?)

-ran many different programs to check my hard disk for errors and try to fix them (most didn't manage to do much because my hard drive got disconnected, while others showed no error)

-some antivirus software to check for potential issues - there were none

Some things I noticed:

-almost always when I check the notifications, there is one from Security and Maintenance asking to scan drive for errors - nothing happens when I click it

-the hard drive keeps restarting (a.k.a clicking noises) randomly

It's worth mentioning that I run Windows 10 and it's installed on my SSD. Also, the first time I noticed something was wrong was after I downloaded a big video file and when I tried to play it, there were lots of interruptions. The next morning I got the errors and disconnections (over night the laptop was powered on and running my torrent program).

Maybe there could be something wrong with the cable connecting my hard drive, but I have no idea how to check that, since my old computer has different cables and I couldn't find a similar cable online.

Do you have any ideas that could help me solve this issue ?

Comment: It almost sounds like a laptop design flaw - with the combined use of HDD and SSD drawing too much power.

Comment: I hope it's not. It's a 17 inch Lenovo Y700, I bought it last year, and it had an empty M.2 slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having this issue, this is what I found that helps:

1. Computer Management
2. Device Manager
3. IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers
4. Properties
5. Driver
6. Update
7. Browse
8. Pick from a list of available drivers
9. Standart SATA AHCI Controller
10. Next, Close and Restart

For some reason, my HDD stopped getting disconnected, although it's still kind of slow.

EDIT:
It was too slow so I had to buy a HDD rack and use it as an external hard drive. I really suggest this approach for everyone having this issue, since the rack is way cheaper than other solutions.